# Spark SQL ODBC Connection not connected

Tags: odbc, apache-spark, thrift

I have build the spark source using the following command

```
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.5 -Dhadoop.version=2.5.2 -Phive -Phive-1.1.0 -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean package
```

I have started the thrift server using the following command

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2 --master local[*]   file:///c:/spark-1.3.1/sql/hive-thriftserver/target/spark-hive-thriftserver_2.10-1.3.1.jar
```

Connected the thriftserver in beeline using the following command

```
Jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
```

Created the table named as people using the following query

```
Create table people(Name String);
Load data local inpath ‘C:\spark-1.3.1\examples\src\main\resources\people.txt’ overwrite into table people;
```

How to read this table from C# application using odbc connection or thrift library?

I have use the following code snippet to read the table using C# code generated by thrift and Thrift dll

```
Console.WriteLine("Thrift hive server for Spark SQL Connection....");

TSocket hiveSocket = new TSocket("localhost", 10000);
TBinaryProtocol protocol =new TBinaryProtocol(hiveSocket);
ThriftHive.Client client = new ThriftHive.Client(protocol);

if (!hiveSocket.IsOpen)
{
    hiveSocket.Open();
}
Console.WriteLine("Thrift server connected");

client.execute("select * from people1");
```

But i can not execute the query.

Comment: What did you try so far to read this table and where did you get stuck with what problem?

Comment: Hi Jens , Thank you for your response , here i have added the C# code snippet i have tried but it did not working for me

Comment: "*But i can not execute the query*" - [Any error messages? If not, what does "*i can not execute the query*" mean exactly?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There is no response.it does not through error /exception

Answer (score 0):

It is not throwing any error or exception because there was probably no error and the processing worked. You just need to actually retrieve the results using client.fetchAll().